# Garbled serial console output even with correct baud rate

Tags: tty, serial-port, serial-console, stty, ttyusb

I'm trying to connect to a headless NAS box via serial console, and have reached a wall that even Google can't seem to help with.

I have a USB to 3.5mm serial cable, with the USB end going into my laptop. I've checked the baud rate on the NAS and it shows as 115200:

```
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
closing_wait: 3000
Flags: spd_normal skip_test
```

On my laptop I'm using `gtkterm` and have set `/dev/ttyUSB0` (what the cable appears as when connected) to 115200 baud, but the output from the NAS is complete gibberish. I've messed around with other baud rates, parity, # of bits, stopbits etc, but can't get anything readable.

To add to the confusion, trying to get the information on the laptop with `setserial` gives:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0, Line 0, UART: 16654, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
Baud_base: 460800, close_delay: 0, divisor: 0
closing_wait: infinite
Flags: spd_normal
```

Which obviously seems wrong, but I can't change anything as I get `Cannot set serial info: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Yet, stty shows the same settings as I configured in gtkterm:

```
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
min = 1; time = 0;
ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

At this point I really cannot think of what else to do. If anyone has any ideas or can direct me to a better place to ask I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure it is rs232 and not ttl voltage levels? Most NAS dont provide a serial port, so presumably this is a debug connection.Measure the voltages on the pins.

Comment: I know the cable I'm using says it uses 3.3v for the tx and rx pins, which from what I know is standard correct? I'll try to measure the voltages of the 3.5mm jack on the NAS itself to see if it varies. BTW, this 3.5mm jack isn't for audio as it's labeled COM1 on the motherboard.

Comment: Update - the tx and rx pins on the NAS side are 2V, while when the cable is connected they measure 4V, so it looks like you are correct. Guess I need to buy a different cable.

Comment: If you have specific details on the NAS type and board and 3.5mm connection you could try asking for help on sister site [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I might just do that.